# A trace inquality for the product of symmetric PSD matrices

Tags: statistics, inequality, trace

I'm estimating the expectation of a quadratic form, using two different estimators, and would like to compare the variances. The first is a MC estimator, and the other is the Hutchinson estimator. I would like to show that the Hutchinson estimator has a lower variance than the MC estimator.

The MC estimator of the expectation of the quadratic form looks like follows.
$$
 E( x^T A x) \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^T A x_i,
$$
where $A$ is a symmetric matrix, and $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,B)$ is a normal distributed R.V. $\textit{The Matrix Cookbook}$ gives the variance of stochastic quadratic forms, and the variance of the MC estimator, using one sample of $x$, is
\begin{align}
\text{Var}\,(x^T A x) & = \text{tr}\,(AB (A+A^T)B) + \mu^T(A+A^T) B (A+A^T)\mu \\\
& = 2 \left(\text{tr}\,((AB)^2) + 2||RA\mu||_2^2\right),
\end{align}
where $R$ is a Cholesky factor of the symmetric $B$.

Instead of estimating the expectation using the MC method above, one could use the identity
$$
E(x^TAx) = \text{tr}\, (AB) + \mu^T A \mu,
$$
and use the Hutchinson estimator on the trace instead. The variance of the Hutchinson estimator for the trace of AB is
$$
\text{Var}(e^TABe) = 2\sum_ {i\neq j} (AB)_{ij}^2 = 2\left(||AB||_F^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n(AB)_{ii}^2\right)
$$
Here, the probing vectors $e$ are Rademacher vectors. To compare these expressions, I rewrite the Frobenius norm as a trace:
$$
||AB||_F^2 = \text{tr}\, (A^2B^2)
$$
My question is then: is it true that
$$
\text{tr}\, (A^2B^2) -\sum_{i=1}^n(AB)_{ii}^2 - 2||RA\mu||_2^2 \leq \text{tr}\,((AB)^2)?
$$